# EC2 AMI for CentOS 5.x 64-bit

Tags: amazon-ec2

Which AMI would you suggest for CentOS 5.x 64-bit?  There is quite a large list but I am clueless as to how to make my decision based on the list here:

http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/kbcategory.jspa?categoryID=208&resultOffset=0&sortField=107&sortOrder=0&filterEntryTypeID=-1

(I tried 'Rating' but that's too subjective)

I also don't want to build my own AMI (for now).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CentOS AMI's prepared by RightScale are probably sufficient.  See http://support.rightscale.com/18-Release_Notes/02-AMI/RightImages_Release_Notes for details and a list of AMI identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

You can also browse and filter the Amazon Machine Images - here is a list showing
[CentOS x64  with an ebs root volume](https://aws.amazon.com/amis?architecture=x86_64&platform=Cent+OS&root_device_type=ebs&selection=platform%2Broot_device_type%2Barchitecture). You can also check out the [page from CentOS](http://wiki.centos.org/Cloud/AWS) discussing how to get started with Amazon and perhaps use one of their AMIs from the Marketplace - which appear to be free from software costs (you just have to pay the amazon usage fees).

[screenshot-with-shadow.png http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/5056/6zli.png](https://aws.amazon.com/amis?architecture=x86_64&platform=Cent+OS&root_device_type=ebs&selection=platform%2Broot_device_type%2Barchitecture)